# Error running Jetty 9.3.6 with JSF 2.2.12 and CDI

Tags: jetty, cdi, jsf-2.2

If I try to run jetty 9.3.6 with JSF 2.2.12 AND CDI I get the Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
```

This is what I have done.

**1. Preparing Jetty**

First i downloaded and extracted jetty version 9.3.6.v20151106 and created a "*MyJettyBase*" directory parallel to the distribution (jetty home)

In the first run, i wanted to get JSF running without CDI. So I changed to "*MyJettyBase*" and entered:

```
java -jar ../jetty-distribution-9.3.6.v20151106/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy,jsp
```

This created a webapps directory and a start.ini file in my base dir "MyJettyBase"

"*start.ini*"

```
--module=server
--module=http
--module=deploy
--module=jsp
```

**2. Creating project**

I created a simple project which looks like this:

```
 - jetty_test
  - src
   - main
   - java
    - de.jettytest.beans
     - HelloWorld.java
  - resources
  - webapp
   - WEB-INF
    - web.xml
   - home.xhtml
 - test
  - java
  - resources
 - build.gradle
 - settings.gradle
```

"*settings.gradle*"

```
rootProject.name = 'jetty_test'
```

"*build.gradle*"

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    jettyVersion = "9.3.6.v20151106"
    jsfVersion = "2.2.12"
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-servlet', version:jettyVersion
    // JSF
    compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-api', version: jsfVersion
    compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-impl', version: jsfVersion
}

subprojects{
  apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```

"*web.xml*"

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <!-- Get JSF 2.2 to work, moraja implementation -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

"*home.xhtml*"

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<head>
    <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
</head>
<body>

<h:outputText value="#{2+2}"/>
#{helloWorld.message}

<h:form>
    <h:button value="#{helloWorld.message}">asd</h:button>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

"*HelloWorld.java*"

```
package de.jettytest.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name="helloWorld", eager = true)
public class HelloWorld {
    public HelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld started!");
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return "Hellp World!!";
    }
}
```

**3. build and deploy**

Now I've just created the war with "gradle war", copied it to MyJettyBase/webapps and started jetty with

```
java -jar ../jetty-distribution-9.3.6.v20151106/start.jar
```

This did work without problems! JSF was running

**4. Adding CDI support**

This is where it all went wrong.

I was following the explanation on: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-weld.html

I added the sugested lines to my web.xml so it looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

     <!-- CDI -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <!-- Get JSF 2.2 to work, moraja implementation -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and changed start.ini to this:

```
--module=server
--module=http
--module=deploy
--module=jsp
--module=cdi
```

Then i entered the command:
java -jar ../jetty-distribution-9.3.6.v20151106/start.jar --create-files

to download the libraries.

Now, when I try to start jetty again with the new jetty_test.war, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:382)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:270)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:543)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:382)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:270)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:543)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:835)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:808)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
2016-01-29 19:25:54.165:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6a55299e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-01-29 19:25:54.166:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1842ms
```

Comment: JSF is not provided by Jetty, it likely needs to be bundled with your WebApp's `WEB-INF/lib/`

Comment: What version of weld are you using?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt JSF did work!

Comment: @JohnAment Iam not sure, seems like 2.2 :[http://s10.postimg.org/8k58o8acp/Screenshot_20160130_065244.png]

Comment: I'd recommend going to the latest weld, 2.3.  If you have a pom file to share, it would help debug further.

Comment: hm, I am using gradle, not maven. The gradle file is visible in the post. There are no cdi libs because I did not yet implement anything. Only activated the jetty cdi module. The CDI version seems to depend on jetty.